# What is the correct use of hyphens and capitals in "Big Brother style pop competition"?

Tags: orthography, capitalization, hyphenation, quotation-marks, italics

Not sure it technically should have any, but *a Big Brother style pop competition* feels like quite a mouthful as it is so I’m wondering whether hyphens might help.

Also want to check the capitalization of *Big Brother* is accurate.

Comment: When most people see "Big Brother" capitalized, they do not really think _dance_.. What is the actual context in which you would like to use it? Use of hyphens is mostly a style issue. See; https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/403173/hyphenation-adjectives-and-attributive-words

Comment: Probable duplicate of: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/2977 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/361156 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/51665 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/2908 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/11780 https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29036 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/15054 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/294948 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/184415 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/79319 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/480277 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/222825 and many more besides.

Comment: Because of the open compound, use an en dash: *Big Brother–style pop competition*. (That is suggested by *The Chicago Manual of Style*.) Or simply *a pop competition in the style of Big Brother*.